# javascript - chrome extension: manipulate txt file in the same directory of the js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that do some simple stuff. now, I made a `.txt` file that hold some url's, and stored it in the same directory, the `.js` file that hold the logic, to read from him and write to him (which I will create when I know how too).

the problem is, I didn't find any info about accessing file with javascript.

so I thought maybe is not possible?

- the extension will not be upload the chrome store, so it will be working only on my PC.
- if is not possible, can you recommend me for a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.*` API does not provide any methods to perform file I\O. However, it allows you to read\write data using `chrome.storage` API, or using more old-fashioned `chrome.cookies` API. I recommend to use `chrome.storage` to achieve your goal.